# Is it possible to get both angular position and edge counting for an NI quadrature encoder from the same DAQ channel in LabVIEW?

Tags: position, labview

I tried to run the code below, but it doesn't let me select the same DAQ channel for both readings, despite the fact they should be taken from the same DAQ channel/encoder. Any suggestions would be welcome.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You **can** use the same *input terminal* to perform both measurements, but you **cannot** use the same *counter* to do so. I cannot see the values for your `Counter(s)` IO Controls, but I suspect they are requesting the driver use the same counter to do two different things.

Try using two counters like this instead. See how `PFI8` is used as the input terminal for both tasks:

[image]